# Split and sort Pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, split

I have a pandas dataframe

```
         values
0      x15_2_30
1     x15_3_137
2      x15_6_26
3     x15_9_139
4    x15_10_143
..          ...
266  x208_6_153
267  x210_2_147
268  x211_1_155
269   x212_3_28
270   x212_5_25
```

I would like to sort this dataframe according to the ascending of number in the middle than number at last.

Preferred output is like that

```
x15_1_4
x12_1_8
x25_1_12
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the middle number and last number with regex all in one go:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text = """
values
x15_6_30
x15_6_26
x15_3_137
x15_9_139
x15_10_143
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+', header=0)

df[['middle_number', 'last_number']] = df['values'].str.extract(
    pat='_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)', 
    expand=True,
).astype(int)

df.sort_values(by=['middle_number', 'last_number', 'values'])

+----+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|    | values     |   middle_number |   last_number |
|----+------------+-----------------+---------------|
|  2 | x15_3_137  |               3 |           137 |
|  1 | x15_6_26   |               6 |            26 |
|  0 | x15_6_30   |               6 |            30 |
|  3 | x15_9_139  |               9 |           139 |
|  4 | x15_10_143 |              10 |           143 |
+----+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

An even simpler solution would be to use [.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and split on the underscore. 
Using parameter `.str.split(expand=True)` makes sure you get all 3 values from the split in 3 separate columns:

```
df[['first_value', 'middle_value', 'last_value']] = df['values'].str.split(
    pat='_', 
    expand=True,
)

df[['middle_value', 'last_value']] = df[['middle_value', 'last_value']].astype(int)

df = df.sort_values(by=['middle_value', 'last_value', 'first_value'])

+----+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|    | values     | first_value   |   middle_value |   last_value |
|----+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------|
|  2 | x15_3_137  | x15           |              3 |          137 |
|  1 | x15_6_26   | x15           |              6 |           26 |
|  0 | x15_6_30   | x15           |              6 |           30 |
|  3 | x15_9_139  | x15           |              9 |          139 |
|  4 | x15_10_143 | x15           |             10 |          143 |
+----+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Btw, I splitted answers like you, but then someone explian me it is wrong (but it was some 3 years ago, so I dont remember reason(s)), so I stop it.

Comment: @jezrael: Community pressure, I guess it's unwritten rules. Although I would prefer separate posts for different answers and let voters decide which answer is the best. If I read this, I would say it's better to post different answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: @jezrael: From that post an interesting quote: If you put two very different answers in one, then one could be a great answer, and one could be a terrible way to do things, but the upvotes (or downvotes) on the good (or bad) answer will drag the other along with it to the top (or bottom).

Comment: yop, agree, it should be unwritten rules

Answer (score 0):

Create a column `temp` in which you assign the value after the last `_` using `str.split().str[index]`. Use it to sort and then drop the column

```
#If Using Last Number
df.assign(temp=df['values'].str.split('_').str[2]).sort_values(by='temp', ascending=False).drop('temp',1)



    values
0      x15_2_30
269   x212_3_28
2      x15_6_26
270   x212_5_25
268  x211_1_155
266  x208_6_153
267  x210_2_147
4    x15_10_143
3     x15_9_139
1     x15_3_137
```